# Why does python returns out-of-bounds when it's not?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Seems to work fine in the first loop, but not the second one. Why is that? I think it should work without problems.

```
import numpy as np

rows = 20
seatsInRow = 1000000
randRow = lambda: np.random.randint(1, rows)
randSeat = lambda: np.random.randint(1, seatsInRow)
cinema = [[1 for x in range(seatsInRow)] for y in range(rows)]

for i in range(1, rows):
    for j in range(1, seatsInRow):
        cinema[i][j] = 1

def checkIfDoubleSeatsLeft():
    for i in range(1, rows):
        for j in range(1, seatsInRow-1):
            if (cinema[i][j]==1 and cinema[i][j+1]==1):
                return True
    return False

def countSeatsLeft():
    count = 0
    for i in range(1, rows):
        for j in range(1, seatsInRow):
            if (cinema[i][j]==1):
                ++count
    return count

selectedRow = 0
selectedSeat = 0
seatsAvailability = True
while (seatsAvailability):
    selectedRow = randRow()
    selectedSeat = randSeat()
    if (selectedSeat < seatsInRow):
        if (cinema[selectedRow][selectedSeat]==1 and cinema[selectedRow][selectedSeat+1]==1):
            cinema[selectedRow][selectedSeat] = 0
            cinema[selectedRow][selectedSeat+1] = 0
    seatsAvailability = checkIfDoubleSeatsLeft()

remainedSeats = countSeatsLeft()
print("Percentage that's left is " + remainedSeats/20000000)
```

Updated the post with full code. Need some more details, here they are )

Comment: Python if statements don't need parentheses `if selectedSeat < seatsInRow:`

Comment: We cannot run this code as you've posted it. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I would suggest first fixing your indentation.

Comment: Added full code.

Comment: *"Why does python returns out-of-bounds when it's not?"* You can trust Python that if you get an out-of-bounds error, then your code *is* accessing something out of bounds.

Comment: You test `selectedSeat < seatsInRow` but later access `selectedSeat+1`. If selected seat is the last element, `selectedSeat = seatsInRow-1`, that access will be out of bounds. Lists and arrays in Python are zero-based with valid subscripts ranging from `0` to `len(lst)-1`.

Comment: A [mcve] for a narrow problem would have only the *shortest possible code* that generates that problem. If there were a way to make Python generate a false out-of-bounds-access error, that should only require two lines -- one to assign a specific value against which that error is known to happen, another to do a lookup; why show all the other, unrelated code?

Comment: Because people asked me, @CharlesDuffy

Comment: Why does it work in the first for though? @RolandW

Comment: @RandomGamoraMax, you were asked for a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is **not** the same as "all" your code, and someone who accepted a complete code dump that wasn't trimmed to the shortest thing that would reproduce the error (without needing any changes or additions) as a MCVE wasn't following the rules strictly.

Comment: ...to put it a little differently, the original code wasn't a MCVE because it wasn't complete; the new code isn't a MCVE because it isn't minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*selectedSeat* can be equal to *seatsInRow* at most, which is also the Y dimension of your matrix. You can thus not acces your matrix at indices higher than *seatsInRow - 1*. Yet, you do exactly this in these two lines:

```
if (cinema[selectedRow][selectedSeat]==1 and cinema[selectedRow][selectedSeat+1]==1):
cinema[selectedRow][selectedSeat+1] = 0
```

So you have to make sure that *randSeat()* returns a value that is at most equal to *seatsInRow - 1*:

```
randSeat = lambda: np.random.randint(1, seatsInRow - 1)
```

Also, you cannot just merge a float with a string, this needs proper formatting:

```
print("Percentage that's left is {}".format(remainedSeats/20000000))
```